# ipython run without destroying global variables defined in the target file

Tags: python, ipython

I want to define some globals in some number crunching work I am doing, I am incrementally writing the script and don't want previous result to keep being loaded/recalculated. One approach is to split out mature code into a separate file and only `python run` interactively new code. However I just want to do it in a single file for speed of development.

I was under the assumption that a global defined in a file would persist between invocations of `run`, but they do not.

So my script has the following chunk if code :

```
if globals().has_key('all_post_freq') != True:
    print "creating all post freq var"
    global all_post_freq
    all_post_freq = all_post_freq_("pickle/all_post_freq.pickle")
```

How do I retain all_post_freq between invocations of `ipython run`

**edit**

ok I have split stuff up into files, but I know there must be a way of doing what I need to do :D

Comment: The first line you show could be clearer, e.g. `if 'all_post_freq' not in globals()`:

Comment: indeed, coming back to python after a bit of a hiatus, when something doesn't work I tinker with it irrationally . That line is one such tinkering session lol:D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `%run` a file, it is normally started in a blank namespace, and its globals are added to the interactive namespace when it finishes. There's a `-i` flag which will run it directly in the interactive namespace, so it will see variables you've already defined:

```
%run -i myscript.py
```